# Android: handler not canceling correctly

Tags: java, android, handler

I have a handler in my code that runs every X seconds. Every time it runs, it executes a task. When the task is executed 4 times without user interaction, I have it set to go back to my main activity. Here is the handler code:

```
    final Handler h1 = new Handler();
    final int delay1 = 400;

    h1.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            enableRandomButton();
            buttonsInPlay = sumVector(greenButtons);

            if (buttonsInPlay >= 4){

                if (currentScore > highScore){
                    highScore = currentScore;
                }

                // GO TO SCORE SCREEN
                h1.removeCallbacks(this);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, Main.class);
                Game.this.startActivity(intent);
                Game.this.finish();
            }

            h1.postDelayed(this, delay1);
        }
    }, delay1);
```

When I get to the point where it goes back to the main screen, it does. However, once it goes back to the main screen, It KEEPS launching new main activities, indefinitely. I suspect that this handler is not getting canceled correctly for some reason. If there is no issue with my code above, I will be happy to share the rest of my code (mostly my Android life cycle methods etc). Thanks!

Comment: "I have it set to go back to my main activity." - You're not really going back; you're starting a new instance of the `Activity`. If you want to go back, just `finish()` the current `Activity`. Also, I would suspect that it's the fact that you're starting a new instance that's causing the described behavior, but you'd need to post more code for us to be able to determine that.

Comment: In my code I'm clearly calling Game.this.finish(); though. Do I need to call finish before starting the intent?

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my comment. You should _just_ `finish()`. If your main `Activity` is still in the back stack, it will return to the previous instance. You don't need to start a new one.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Currently in my game, I don't have my score screen setup yet, so instead of going there (which wont be in the stack), i'm sending it to a new activity (main). If it's doing this weird thing with creating the main activity an infinite amount of times, it should do the same when I have my score screen up and running.

Comment: Oh, wait, I see it now. `h1.postDelayed(this, delay1);` should be in an `else` for the `if (buttonsInPlay >= 4)` statement. Otherwise, after the `Runnable` is removed, it just gets posted again.

Comment: Well, the if condition is when the game should end - if (buttonsInPlay >= 4){ } .... h1.removeCallBacks still falls within that. So when ending the game it gets called. Yet it's not working correctly. I just switched from a handler to a timertask and it's working correctly. Everything is the same essentially, but instead of removing the handler callback, I'm calling timertask.cancel() and timertask.purge(). This is all with the same exact flow as above. I'm not sure if I should "answer" my question with this, as it's a work around, rather than a solution using a handler.

Comment: "Well, the if condition is when the game should end - if (buttonsInPlay >= 4){ } .... h1.removeCallBacks still falls within that." - Right, but immediately after that `if` where you `removeCallbacks()`, you're posting the `Runnable` again. It's the same as not having called `removeCallbacks()` at all. Only if the game isn't over should you repost the `Runnable`, so `postDelayed()` should be in an `else`.

Comment: Oh wow.. I never considered that it would finish running that entire segment, even if I was finishing the activity. It's working as intended now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.  Just don't post the Runnable again when the terminating condition is met.  Also bear in mind that finish() is not immediate and does not break the execution of the current unit of work:

```
        if (buttonsInPlay >= 4){
            if (currentScore > highScore){
                highScore = currentScore;
            }

            // GO TO SCORE SCREEN
            // h1.removeCallbacks(this);  // not helpful, nothing is scheduled at this moment
            Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, Main.class);
            Game.this.startActivity(intent);
            Game.this.finish();
        }
        else {
            // Only reschedule if we have to continue
            h1.postDelayed(this, delay1);
        }
```